# HTML/Javascript for controlling lottie animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, lottie

I am looking to control a Lottie animation through the scroll. I want the Lottie animation to play when it is in a sticky container. Imagine that you have the Lottie animation in a sticky container. As a user scrolls down, the animation plays and there is additional text that fades in/out at certain points of the scroll event.

Right now, I am having an issue with the animation actually playing. What I want is for the animation to play as I scroll through the sticky controller. I have a code pen created to demo my current code. Could someone take a look and see what is the issue with the code?

https://codepen.io/philm001/pen/rNKeEKR

```
<!--
// Post-Specific Javascript Code
-->
<!--
// Header Cover
-->
<style>
    #cover {
        position: sticky;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: black;
    }

    #cover_container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw !important;
        left: 50% !important;
        transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
        height: 400vh;
        background: lightgray;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }

    #lotti {
        position: absolute;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
        background: navy;
    }

    /* Override to enable sticky scrollers to work */
    #td-outer-wrap{
        overflow: visible;
    }
</style>

<!--<script src="../../build/player/lottie.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>

<script defer="">

    /**
    * Returns the percentage (0 to 100) of the way scrolled through a sticky container
    * @param {*} stickyContainer        CSS selector to get the parent container holding container holding the sticky element
    * @param {*} stickyElement      CSS selector to get the sticky element
    * @returns 
    */
    function getPercentScrolled(stickyContainer, stickyElement) {
        container = document.querySelector(stickyContainer).getBoundingClientRect();
        stickyElement = document.querySelector(stickyElement).getBoundingClientRect();

        let scrollPosition = -container.top; // Sticky height >= viewport height
        let scrollHeight = container.height - stickyElement.height;

        let percentScrolled = (scrollPosition / scrollHeight) * 100;
        if (percentScrolled > 100) percentScrolled = 100;
        else if (percentScrolled < 0) percentScrolled = 0;

        //console.log('stickyElement.heightt: ', stickyElement.height);
        //console.log('scrollPosition: ', scrollPosition);
        //console.log('scrollHeight: ', scrollHeight);
        //console.log('percentScrolled: ', percentScrolled);

        return percentScrolled;
    }

    /////////////////////////////
    // Main scroll event listener
    //////////////////////////////

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

        //-------------------------------
        // Top Cover animations
        //-------------------------------

        let percentScrolled = getPercentScrolled('#cover_container', '#cover');
    });

    // Adjust the class names for the various wordpress-generated covers to relocate them in their parent elements
    window.onload = function() { 
        // Force trigger the scroll event to update the animation states
        /*window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll'));

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        var anim;
        var elem = document.getElementById("lottie");
        var animData = {
            container: elem,
            renderer: "svg",
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            rendererSettings: {
                progressiveLoad: true,
                preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid meet",
                imagePreserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid meet"
            },
            path: "https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_4hgob7et.json"
        };

        anim = lottie.loadAnimation(animData);
        anim.setSubframe(false);

        var animAPI;

        anim.addEventListener("DOMLoaded", function() {
            animAPI = lottie_api.createAnimationApi(anim);
        });*/
    });

</script>



<div id="cover_container">
    <div id="cover">
        <div id="lotti">
      <lottie-player id="test" interactivitytype="seek" interactivitymode="scroll" visibilitystart="0" visibilityend="1" framesstart="0" framesend="21" totalframes="21" src="https://assets5.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/zc3XRzudyWE36ZBJr7PIkkqq0PFIrIBgp4ojqShI/newAnimation.json" speed="3" background="transparent" class="lottie-player mx-auto" style="width:315px;height:280px;overflow:visible"></lottie-player>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```